# "Iterate" vs. "Iterate over"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is it redundant to say *iterate over*? I cannot think of any other word that you'd use with *iterate*, so is it acceptable (or correct, even) to drop the *over*?

Answer (score 13):

Iterate over *what*? I guess that is the point.

To 'iterate' is to repeat something, say, an action, so we can *iterate* a procedure, or we can *iterate over x*, or *iterate through x*. So:

> We iterate over numbers one to ten.
>
> We iterate through each entry.
>
> We iterate the above procedure.
>
> The above procedure is iterative.

Note the difference between iterate and reiterate as some might find it subtle, where reiterated becomes continuous:

> **Iterate**
>
> To say or perform again; repeat.
>
> **Reiterate**
>
> To say or do again or repeatedly.

In this case:

> We reiterate the above procedure until we get a satisfying result.

Comment: Is there really a difference between *iterate* and *reiterate*? It seems to me that (except maybe in mathematical language) they're synonyms.

Comment: @Peter Shor: "Reiterate" has the specific meaning of saying something again (and again). *Allow me to reiterate my earlier contention that this method iterates over all the objects in the array and sorts them according to the `age` property.*

Answer (score 6):

Iterate is a transitive verb, meaning to repeat something, which is often used mathematically: if you want to say you do a procedure again, you would say

> We iterate the procedure.

In mathematics or computing, if you want to say you do the procedure on every object in some set $S$, you would say

> We iterate the procedure over the set $S$.

If the person you're talking to knows what the procedure is, you can drop it from the sentence:

> We iterate over the set $S$.

You need the word *over* in this sentence, because you're not iterating the set; you're iterating the procedure.

---

If you're not talking about mathematics, I don't think you'd use the preposition *over:*

> We will iterate the decontamination procedure for every house in the town.

or, if your audience understands you're talking about decontamination:

> We will iterate for every house in the town.